# String array for filter out numbers not working

Tags: java, string, filter

(school task)

I have a

```
 String stringArray[]
```

that consists of words from a text file, split by "\\W+"

I then have two more string arrays:

```
    String acceptedWords[];
    String rejectedWords[];
```

I want to go through the

```
 String stringArray[]
```

and "filter out" some stuff. For example, I do not want numbers in my list (or other stuff that is not qualifies as a word). Say if the elements in the stringArray is:

```
 stringArray = ["Hei", "Luise", "99", "Per", "H32l"];
```

I want to take out 99, and the H32l (bc it is not a valid word), and put it in the:

```
  String rejectedWords[];
```

and put the valid words in the:

```
 String acceptedWords[];
```

so that I can use the words in `acceptedWords` to run a binary tree to sort the words I got.

This is what I got, but it is not working:

```
    String acceptedWords[];
    String rejectedWords[];

    for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
        if (stringArray.equals("[0-9]")) {
            rejectedWords = stringArray[i];
        } else {
            acceptedWords = stringArray[i];
        }
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rejectedWords));
```

Comment: replace `stringArray.equals("[0-9]")` with `stringArray.matchs("[0-9]+")`

Comment: Just to add what @YCF_L has already mentioned, without `+` sign after `[]`, it will check only for one digit.